# how to compile protobuf with maven plugin?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

i had import maven plugin  which used for proto compile , and  the pom.xml is below

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
            <protocExecutable>/home/pengpeng/tools/protoc/bin/protoc</protocExecutable>
            <protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/proto</protoSourceRoot>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

here is my proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

//option java_multiple_files = true;
package com.ifx.connect.proto;
option java_package = "com.ifx.connect.proto";
option java_outer_classname = "Message";


message Message{

  int32 header = 1;

  string jwt = 2; // java-web-token



}
```

but when i tried compile proto , it orrur the error `protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information.` . i had no run protoc before , and  how to fix it ?

Comment: it is very funny , after asking the question ,  i found the problem , the outer classname  ```Message``` is invaild .    i  will close the question

Comment: Stumbled upon this question and noticed:

`<outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>`

which means to put generated sources to the same source root as manually supported source code. Please do not do that. Use `target/generated-sources/xxx` instead. That is supported by majority of IDEs, maven etc